# Postgres+Docker+Django OperationalError

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I've got an issue with connecting PostgreSQL with Django using Docker.
Error: `web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

If I don't use Docker (just runserver command in prompt) it looks as it should, no errors. In another project Docker works correctly with this config.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python bookstore/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER= postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB= postgres
```

My settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be because you have a space before postgres in your environment settings?

Comment: see https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/ for a working example

Comment: IT IS! LOVE YOU BRO